# Vertically alignment of images in list

Tags: css, web, alignment

I'm trying to make a list containing images and input fields. I would like them to be vertically aligned, but all approaches so far has been without success. I've tried to set the line-height, fiddle with paddings and margins and create the entire layout with tables instead of li with no luck.

The markup in question can be found [here](http://jsfiddle.net/kg8HG/649/). Any ideas?

Comment: it's not `vertial-align: middle;` it's `vertical-align: middle;`

Comment: yes, you are right. Unfortunately it doesn't work either.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

EDIT:

I originally only tried in chrome.  I think it might have been because of inconsistent input height.

Give this one a try..

http://jsfiddle.net/kg8HG/734/

Comment: It still doesn't seem centered to me although a lot closer. How did you choose the line-heights of 30 and 25 respectively?

Comment: But as far as I can tell the images isn't centered even in the updated version.

Comment: Last edit works. But I still don't understand why it is neccessary to have a different line-hight. How did you come up with 20 and 18?

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried Display?
http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/pr_class_display.asp

```
#pager ul li{
display:block;
}
```

Comment: I have tried that as well. This result in a horizontal list instead of a vertical. http://jsfiddle.net/kg8HG/705/.

Comment: @Niels works when I try it. you are overriding the display:inline you previously defined, though. As it is now defined twice

Comment: Yes I know i defined it twice, but I get the same result in both cases. I get a vertical list, just as the link you posted says,

Comment: Oh, the display: block should be combined with a float: left? This gives a horizontal line, but the images are still not centered.